# What is the best way to keep up a schedule with AlarmManager?

Tags: android, calendar, alarmmanager

I am trying to think about how to structure my app. It will have the user input various times to silence and unsilence your phone, and more times can be added and taken away from this schedule at any time. I am trying to figure out what would be the best way to go about this, having one Calendar with all times on it, or one Calendar per object (each object in the app store info about when to silence and unsilence the phone), along with the math that goes along with when to actually silence and unsilence the phone due to overlapping schedules (which is expected).

What is the best way to structure this?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=alarmmanager+github&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#hl=ru&client=firefox-a&hs=KMJ&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=android+alarmmanager+github&oq=android+alarmmanager+github&gs_l=serp.3...5351.6418.0.6647.8.8.0.0.0.2.146.1057.0j8.8.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.-nnQDGpJi_g&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43148975,d.Yms&fp=8c7bd045a352fdc9&biw=1280&bih=687

Comment: From what it sounds like you are asking, you would probably want separate objects with a calendar as a parameter for each but not sure. Also, you may have better luck on a question like this at programmers.stackexchange.com That site is more about design of apps where SO is more about the actual coding. Good luck!